# How to slice an array into certain subarray?

Tags: python, arrays, slice

I have an array like

```
[
    {'name':'a'},
    {'name':'b'},
    {'name':'c'},
    {'name':'d'},
    {'name':'e'},
    {'name':'f'}
]
```

The array length is 6, now I want to split it into 4 subarray, I expect the result will like

```
[
    [
         {'name':'a'},
         {'name':'e'}
    ],
    [
         {'name':'b'},
         {'name':'f'}
    ],
    [
         {'name':'c'}
    ],
    [
         {'name':'d'}
    ]
]
```

I can do it with loop, and I wonder is there any other smart way to do this?

My bad, maybe I don't make it clear here is my code:

```
def uploadSheets(servers, sheets):
serverLen = len(servers.keys())
sheetsLen = len(sheets)
index = 0
count = int(cookieLen / serverLen)
left = int(sheetsLen % serverLen)
for key in servers.keys():
    ip = servers[key]
    remoteExecute(user=user, ip=ip, command='rm /home/pdd/sheets/*', passwd=passwd)
    for j in range(count):
        localPath = '../deploy/' + sheets[index * count + j]
        remotePath = '/home/pdd/sheets/'
        fileTransfer(localPath=localPath, ip=ip, user=user, destPath=remotePath, passwd=passwd)
    index += 1
for i in range(left):
    localPath = './deploy/' + sheets[index * count + i]
    remotePath = '/home/pdd/sheets/'
    ip = servers[list(servers.keys())[i]]

print('finish')
```

I have a group of servers, and daily I upload more and more files to each of the servers without duplication.And there is a pattern that the file name cloed to each other better send to a different server.

Like I have 101 apples, 20 baskets, I put the Apple to the busket from busket1 to busket20, at the end, the busket1 will have 6 apples and the others have 5.

Comment: can you explain more the logic in it?

Comment: What's the criteria for grouping elements together? Why is `a` and `e` grouped but `c` and `d` not?

Comment: `[ [arr[0],arr[4]], [arr[1],arr[5]], [arr[2]], [arr[3]] ]`

Comment: Perhaps you should include the loop code in the question so people can see exactly what you're trying to do. I assume you have some pattern you want to apply for an input array of variable size, otherwise why bother even with a loop?

Comment: lists and dictionaries require loops; this isn't `numpy` with compiled array operations (for numeric values).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the logic is built up to arrange elements together, here is something you could do:

```
list1 = [{'name':'a'},{'name':'b'},{'name':'c'},{'name':'d'},{'name':'e'},{'name':'f'}]
logic = [[0,4], [1,5], [2,3]]
print([[list1[y] for y in x] for x in logic])
```

**Output**

```
[[{'name': 'a'}, {'name': 'e'}],
 [{'name': 'b'}, {'name': 'f'}],
 [{'name': 'c'}, {'name': 'd'}]]
```